# "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'url' " in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am getting the following error in IE (but not Firefox):

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'url' 
AjaxSetup.js?version=7b8dcb65-17d1-437f-9594-0621c779427c, line 28 character 2
```

There are several other posts with errors like this (for other objects besides url), but all of them seem to have answers along the lines of "such a function doesn't exist in jquery" or "such a function is invalid to use in this context", and neither seems to apply to my situation at least as far as I can tell.

The function containing the line number that the error is referring to is:

```
function redirectToLogin() {
    var redirUrl = $.url().attr("path");
    if ($.url().attr("query").length > 0) {
        redirUrl += "?" + $.url().attr("query");
    }
    top.window.location = "/Shared/Logout?redir=" + encodeURIComponent(redirUrl);
    return;
}
```

where line 28 is the second line of the function above.

More strangely, while on the offending page (from which the above function gets called), when I type `$.url()` or `$.url().attr("path")` into the IE Developer Tools console, it returns the correct object and string, respectively.  The values also seem to stay correct if I "watch" them.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

EDIT:

I found a workaround:

```
function redirectToLogin() {
    top.window.location = "/Shared/Logout?redir=" + encodeURIComponent(location.pathname + location.search);
    return;
}
```

This seems to work and achieve the same thing, so I'm posting it in case it helps someone. However, I would still be curious to find out why the original code using jquery was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess if you say it works in the console that the code is trying to use it before `$.url()` is initialized. Is the url JavaScript included before the AjaxSetup file?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. By url Javascript do you mean the jquery includes?  If so, yes.  My includes are on the master page as follows:
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.url.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/Global.js?<%#VersionQueryString %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/AjaxSetup.js?<%#VersionQueryString %>" type="text/javascript"></script>